# How to print from itertools count object?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm using itertools count method to keep track of how many instances of a class have been created. My simplified code looks something like this:

```
from itertools import count
a = count(1)
a.next()
a.next()
print a
```

> count(3)

I want to print just the "3", without count. Sounds simple right?

Comment: Instead of an iterator, why not use `a = 0` and then `a += 1` to increment it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it sounds simple ... it probably is

```
from itertools import count
a = count(1)

next(a)
next(a)
print next(a)
```

you can also use itertools.islice to skip parts of an iterator

```
from itertools import count,islice
a = count(1)
for item in islice(a,2,4):
    print item
```

Comment: Note that this advances the iterator, which might not be desired. I don't think I'd use `itertools.count` for this at all.